# how to order result by displaying each job type by order

Tags: c#, linq

I have a search query which search for all jobs in the database and than displays them in accordance to the most recent ones filtering the data by date as follows:

```
  result = db.AllJobModel.Where(a => a.JobTitle.Contains(searchTitle) && a.locationName.Contains(searchLocation)).ToList());

      result = (from app in result orderby DateTime.ParseExact(app.PostedDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", null) descending select app).ToList();

result = GetAllJobModelsOrder(result);
```

after that I have a method GetAllJobModelsOrder which displays jobs in order which seems to be work fine but in my case its not ordering jobs so I need to understand where I am wrong:

```
 private List<AllJobModel> GetAllJobModelsOrder(List<AllJobModel> result)
    {
        var list = result.OrderBy(m => m.JobImage.Contains("job1") ? 1 :
                       m.JobImage.Contains("job2") ? 2 :
                       m.JobImage.Contains("job3") ? 3 :
                       m.JobImage.Contains("job4") ? 4 :
                       m.JobImage.Contains("job5") ? 5 :
                       6)
         .ToList();
        return list;
    }
```

The result I get is about 10 jobs from job1 and than followed by other jobs in the same order what I would like to achieve is to filter the most recent jobs than display one job from each type of a job.

An example of the input would be as follows:

```
    AllJobModel allJobModel = new AllJobModel
    {

        JobDescription = "Description",
        JobImage = "Job1",
        JobTitle = "title", 
        locationName = "UK",
        datePosted = "15/06/2020",
    }
```

The output that I get is as follows:

[image: result from query]

In where result should be mixed from different jobs.

Excepted resulta as follows a specific order of job source--1. TotalJob[0] :: 2. MonsterJob[0] :: 3. Redd[0] :: 4. TotalJob[ 1 ] :: 5. MonsterJob[ 1 ] ::6. Redd[ 1 ]:
[image]

I have tried the following solution but list data structure seems to be not stroing data in order:

```
     private List<AllJobModel> GetAllJobModelsOrder(List<AllJobModel> result)
    {

        string lastItem = "";
        List<AllJobModel> list = new List<AllJobModel>();
        int pos = -1;
        while(result.Count != 0)
        {
            for(int i  = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
            {
                if(result[i].JobImage.Contains("reed") && (lastItem == "" || lastItem == "total" || lastItem == "monster"))
                {
                    pos++;
                    list.Insert(pos,result[i]);
                    lastItem = "reed";
                    result.Remove(result[i]);
                    break;
                }else if (result[i].JobImage.Contains("total") && (lastItem == "reed" || lastItem == "monster" || lastItem == ""  ))
                {
                    pos++;
                    list.Insert(pos, result[i]);
                    lastItem = "total";
                    result.Remove(result[i]);
                    break;
                }else if(result[i].JobImage.Contains("monster.png") && (lastItem =="total" || lastItem == "reed" || lastItem == ""  ))
                {
                    pos++;
                    list.Insert(pos, result[i]);
                    lastItem = "monster";
                    result.Remove(result[i]);
                    break;
                }else if(result[i].JobImage.Contains("reed") &&( lastItem == "reed"))
                {
                    if(result.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.JobImage.Contains("total") || a.JobImage.Contains("monster")) != null)
                    {
                        lastItem = "total";
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pos++;
                        list.Insert(pos, result[i]);
                        lastItem = "reed";
                        result.Remove(result[i]);
                        break;
                    }

                }
                else if (result[i].JobImage.Contains("total") && (lastItem == "total"))
                {
                    if (result.FirstOrDefault(a => a.JobImage.Contains("reed") || a.JobImage.Contains("monster")) != null)
                    {
                        lastItem = "monster";
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pos++;
                        list.Insert(pos, result[i]);
                        lastItem = "total";
                        result.Remove(result[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (result[i].JobImage.Contains("monster") && (lastItem == "monster"))
                {
                    if (result.FirstOrDefault(a => a.JobImage.Contains("total") || a.JobImage.Contains("reed")) != null)
                    {
                        lastItem = "reed";
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pos++;
                        list.Insert(pos, result[i]);
                        lastItem = "monster";
                        result.Remove(result[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        return list;


    }
```

also what I found is that the value of the elements in the list is different from what its actual value. So I am not sure if this is an error with my code or with visual studio:

[image]

Comment: Why just don't use `result.OrderBy(m => m.JobImage);`? Or extract a number from `JobImage` field?

Comment: because I would like to display result from each job one by one for example job1 followed by job2 etc taking into consideration the most recent ones

Comment: Can you show us an example of the input to GetAllJobModelsOrder, and the expected output?

Comment: I did add the information that you requested please view the expected result

Comment: So, if you want a "mixed' order of jobs listed, then why do you order them? And if they should be "mixed" in some kind of "order", what is the criteria for ordering them?

Comment: the first criteria is to display the most recent jobs so I need to filter by date. Than the result should be Job1 followed by Job2 followed by Job3 followed by Job4. the second criteria is that if one of the job type such as Job3 contains older jobs but the other jobs still have new Jobs than order should be JOB1 followed by job2 followed by job4. Once a specific date has completed and displayed all jobs than it should move to the next available date in the same pattern   thanks so much for your help and the help you are going to provide

Comment: And yet your example and example data `AllJobModel` never mention or contain "Date". Please edit your question with this information as it is critical to understanding the requirements.

Comment: Yes I did change that I hope that I am making sense now and that I have understood your requirements of updating the post

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below concept here. I am sorting a list based on the numeric value at the end of each string value using Regex.

```
List<string> ls = new List<string>() { "job2", "job1", "job4", "job3" };
ls = ls.OrderBy(x => Regex.Match(x, @"\d+$").Value).ToList();
```

Comment: this is wont order them in where to display a job from each job source please refer to the updated image in my post

Answer (score 0):

Certainly the requirement was not as straight forward as initially thought. Which is why I am offering a second solution.

Having order by and rotate the offering "Firm" in a type of priority list for a set number of times and then just display whatever comes after that requires a custom solution. If the one algorithm you have works and you are happy then great. Otherwise, I have come up with this algorithm.

```
    private static List<AllJobModel> ProcessJobs(List<AllJobModel> l)
    {
        var noPriorityFirst = 2;
        var orderedList = new List<AllJobModel>();
        var priorityImage = new string[] { "TotalJob", "MonsterJob", "Redd" };

        var gl = l.OrderBy(o => o.datePosted).GroupBy(g => g.datePosted).ToList();

        foreach (var g in gl)
        {
            var key = g.Key;
            for (int i = 0; i < noPriorityFirst; i++)
            {
                foreach (var j in priorityImage)
                {
                    var a = l.Where(w => w.datePosted.Equals(key) && w.JobImage.Equals(j)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (a != null)
                    {
                        orderedList.Add(a);
                        var ra = l.Remove(a);
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (var j in l.ToList())
            {
                var a = l.Where(w => w.datePosted.Equals(key)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (a != null)
                {
                    orderedList.Add(a);
                    var ra = l.Remove(a);
                }
            }
        }

        return orderedList;
    }
```

To test this process I have created this Console app:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start");
    var l = CreateTestList();
    var lJobs = ProcessJobs(l);
    lJobs.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.datePosted} : {x.JobImage}"));
}



private static List<AllJobModel> CreateTestList()
{
    var orderedList = new List<AllJobModel>();
    var l = new List<AllJobModel>();
    var priorityImage = new string[] { "TotalJob", "MonsterJob", "Redd" };
    var rand = new Random();

    var startTime = DateTime.Now;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var j = rand.Next(0, priorityImage.Length);
        var h = rand.Next(0, 4);
        var a = new AllJobModel();
        a.JobDescription = "Desc " + i;
        a.JobImage = priorityImage[j];
        a.JobTitle = "Title" + i;
        a.locationName = "UK";
        a.datePosted = startTime.AddDays(h);
        l.Add(a);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var j = rand.Next(0, priorityImage.Length);
        var h = rand.Next(0, 4);
        var a = new AllJobModel();
        a.JobDescription = "Desc " + i;
        a.JobImage = "Job " + i;
        a.JobTitle = "Title" + i;
        a.locationName = "UK";
        a.datePosted = startTime.AddDays(h);
        l.Add(a);
    }

    return l;
}
```